# background color not working with img

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an image that is within the div tag. This div has no background color, but I want to add a background color. but when I add background color are disappearing photos.

For example, cc into the div tag when I add background color  within the div tag are disappearing photos
Codepen.io [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/zjaol/)
  **HTML CODE**

```
       <div class="cc">
<div class="container">  
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/">
</div>
</div>
```

**And CSS CODE:**

```
    body {
  background: #000;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1920px;  
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95% );

}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.cc {

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;

}
```

Comment: Could you simplify the fiddle and the code for us? It's not quite clear what the issue is (and where)

Comment: @chopper i will tel you in my detail. Change cover_container background color in css then you see what happened...

Comment: Usually, when people take-down the code to a minimum that allows to narrow the issue they figure the problem really simply. Have you tried?

Comment: Remove the `z-index: -1` on the image to fix the issue.

Comment: @ralph.m if i remove z-index:-1 then my gradient not working. I try before

Comment: @JoshCrozier How did you do it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes i try dear really. When i add a cover_container background color image was remove. If you try then you can understand me. I don't understand people! I will tell them in my question detail. What i wat to try...

Answer (score 0):

Digging through your CSS, I came across a `z-index: -1`. If you specify this, the image will be rendered behind all elements with a higher z-index. Thus it was hidden

EDIT:

Give your `.img_400px400px` (which has the gradient) a `z-index: 1` and your `.img_400px400px img` a `z-index: 2`. Then your background color, gradient and image show. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfF4P/1/)

Comment: thats right but when i remove z-index then my gradient was not working can you give me one example in my jsfiddle ?

Comment: dear this is your solution. not working http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/WfF4P/2/

Comment: Have a look at my fiddle (in the answer). You clearly won't be able to see the background color or the gradient if the image is in front of it.

Comment: you will right but try here. gradient is not working in your solution. http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/zjaol/

Comment: Works fine for me. The gradient is meant to be over the image, no?